# Send data from scene to scene - react native experimental navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation

So I had an app in which I used react native router flux for navigation; with this library, it was rather easy to move from view to view and send data between them, I think instruction was something like:

Route.nameofview({foo});

and in the other view you would receive the data in this.props.foo. Now I'm working with a updated React native, and I can't just find any documentation in where they specify how to send data between views, anyone has an example or info about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data via navigator method in this way:

```
let passObj = Object.assign({}, Routes.NEXT_VIEW, {
  data: YOUR_DATA
});
this.props.navigator.push(passObj);
```

And you can receive the data in NEXT_VIEW with

```
this.props.route.data
```